# Merging history state object with constructor using knockout merge

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

i'm having issues with merging my history state object with a constructor that i have, that gets saved in the same history state for later use.

Plugin example page: https://rawgit.com/grofit/knockout.merge/master/example.html

Using the example that is shown in knockout merge plugin page that uses a constructor like my own i've built my code but unfortunately since i'm relatively new to knockout i ran into issues.

This is the a piece of code shown inside  knockout merge's example

```
function Person()
        {
            this.Firstname = ko.observable();
            this.Surname = ko.observable();
        }

function ViewModel()
            {
                this.SimpleExampleModel = new Person();

                this.MergeSimpleExample = function() {
                    var personJson = { Firstname: "James", Surname: "Bond" };
                    ko.merge.fromJS(this.SimpleExampleModel, personJson);
                };
        };

            ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Now my code:

(The object that is pushed to the history is the constuctor's observables as an object)

Constructor:

```
    var searchTerm = function () {
        this.MinPrice = ko.observable();     
    };


     lbx.vm = {
        term: new searchTerm(),  
        injectHistory: function () {

              // ko.merge.fromJS(this.term, history.state); Doesn't work
             // var json = ko.toJSON(history.state) - Doesn't work
            //var json = JSON.Parse(history.state) - Doesn't work
           //var json = { MinPrice: 222 }; Works
            var json = { "MinPrice": 222 }; // Works

            ko.merge.fromJS(this.term, json);

            console.log("injected");
        }

    };
```

As you can see according to my testing, whenever i try to turn my JS object into json it doesn't work, but it does if i build the json manually.

Fiddle with my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/Badzpeed/05zdLgxh/1/

As you will see in the fiddle when i popstate, nothing happens, the observable value is always the same and it doesn't throw any error.

Any help would be appreciated !

Thank you in Advance

Comment: A few tips that would make it easier for us to help you. Try to reduce your code example so it *only* shows the issue. There's a *lot* of view model properties and things going on there and I'm guessing they're not *all* needed to repro. Also, be explicit about what "*doesn't work*" mean: an error (which?), wrong data, etc? Finally it might help if you reformat your code for readability (use the live preview). Note that you can edit your question to improve it.

Comment: I'm editing with a single property to be easier. Thank you the the tip ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally fixed my issue, turns out that i forgot to add the constructor to the merge and i also had a double call to the function that was passing the object to my history state, making two of them.

Fixed the issue by changing those two things.

Thank you for your time !